# Adding a blog in asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, blogs

I want to add a blog to mine website[asp.net]. The issue I am facing is how to structure the blog-navigation and storage in the database.

To be more clear here it is.

**example**

While navigating to older posts the address bar says this
http://www.mono-1.com/us/page/2/

And on clicking a post the link opens up with this address
http://www.mono-1.com/us/kristoffer-returns-to-uptown/

For opening the post in a page I do understand that the particular data can be fetched from the database and address link be adjusted

What i dont follow is how to add a fixed number of posts to different pages[../page/2/] [../page/3/] and like wise

Comment: What do you mean "how to add a fixed number of posts to different pages"? Do you mean how to do paging?

Comment: Hi sir what i mean is how to achieve a different address after 4 or 5 posts have been added to a particular page.

Like [../page/1] and when i navigate to older posts [../page/2] is in the address bar which according to mine knowledge depicts a different folder after each 5 posts.

Comment: Sir, When we do paging the page remains the same only different data is retrieved i think.

By the way what my problem is shall i use different folders for each 5 blog posts or wewrite the url using code.

Please do have a look for may be i am not clear enough. http://www.mono-1.com/us/page/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC has route engine.

However, in traditional ASP.Net, you need to rewrite url such as http://urlrewriter.net/.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for reply/

What i want to achieve is here http://www.mono-1.com/us/page/2/
When we move to older posts the url shows a different folder path.

Is it url wewrite as you suggest or any other method. Will be a great help.

Comment: Yes. In asp.net websites, you can rewrite url from `http://www.mono-1.com/default.aspx?lang=us&page=4` to `http://www.mono-1.com/us/page/4/`